How can I make ReadTheDocs theme for Sphinx lay out function parameters nicely for mobile?
The ReadTheDocs theme for Sphinx is a particularly nice and easy to read theme. It works very well on decent width displays. Here's an example:

It also mostly also works very well on very narrow displays (as you'd get looking on mobile). However, at least one thing does poorly: the documentation for parts of a function signature overflow the right hand side. That's because the type of thing being documented ("Parameters:"/"Raises:"/"Returns:") forms a sort of column on the left which uses up a lot of the horizontal space. Here's the same example, showing this problem:

I'd prefer those captions to be on their own line like in the version below (which I manually constructed this with RST syntax), although ideally I'd like there to be less vertical spacing. This still overflows sometimes (with the really long type name) but it's a lot better. I'd even be happy if it was just like this unconditionally, even with wide displays.

Is there a way to make the theme behave like the above image? Perhaps by overriding something in the theme's CSS?
Edit with some extra info: aioresult docs are the site in question. I've found that if I override the style of one of the relevant <dl> tags with display: block (in my browser's style inspector) then it fixes it, but there seem to be dozens of options for display and I don't know what the difference is - I'm not very familiar with CSS. Also, the indentation then looks far too small (not like my final image above). I also don't know how to target the custom CSS at only this type of definition list - it seems like <dl> is used for a lot of other things on the page (e.g. class name and everything underneath).

Inspect the rendered HTML. If it is not a table, then you might be able to do it with custom CSS alone, else you would have to rewrite the output. Alternatively use a theme that styles APIs better, such as Furo or others.

@StevePiercy Thanks, it looks like it's a description list so there's hope. But I'm not familiar enough with CSS (and this theme's CSS generation) to modify it myself – that's why I asked the question! Aside from some minor issues like this one, ReadThrDocs is the best theme I've come across: Furo has very little visual distinction between elements, which is pretty and clean, but not helpful if you're browsing through it quickly to get an overview of a library. (This is subjective of course.)

You can grab only the relevant CSS from any other theme that has a nice API style and use a custom CSS file in your project that overrides what the RTD theme does. Look for relevant DOM selectors.

Here is some custom CSS I created to get the effect. I included it in my docs using the ReadTheDocs guide to How to add custom CSS.
@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
  html.writer-html5 .rst-content dl.field-list { display: block }
}
html.writer-html5 .rst-content dl.field-list > dt { padding-left: 0px }
html.writer-html5 .rst-content { overflow-wrap: break-word }
html.writer-html5 .rst-content dt.sig { display: block !important }

Explanation:

The key is to use display: block for dl.field-list. I used all that qualification because otherwise it was overridden by the more specific CSS in the style itself.
I initially made it conditional on @media screen and (max-width:768px) because this is what the RTD theme uses to decide when to hide the sidebar, but I found it was still overflowing in a window of moderate width, so I changed the threshold to 1024px instead. Some might prefer to get rid of the conditional altogether.
I then found that the indentation was very narrow between <dt> and <dd> (i.e. from a caption like "Returns:" to the content like "The return value is ..."). That's because <dt> was getting an indentation of 1em somehow, which was barely less than the indentation of the <dd>. Setting that to 0 fixed the issue (and that's acceptable for my taste but some might have preferred to add indentation to the <dt> instead. I left this out of the max-width conditional because I even preferred the grid version to not be indented (there's already enough indentation in this theme).
I added overflow-wrap: break-word to fix the problem of very long identifier names.
The last line makes signatures (the blue and grey boxes) always span the whole screen width, rather than only if they take up more than one line. Unlike the others, it's not about overflowing, and it's definitely more subjective. I've included it here because it's still related to narrow displays: the default behaviour looks particularly poor on mobile screens where lots of signatures tend to reach almost to the right hand edge but not quite, so it looks like there's an uneven right margin.

Here's the result on a narrow view port:

Here's the result on a wider view port (but still narrow enough that its matches the max-width:1024px condition):

